# Thunderbolt or Mini display port Connect Macbook Pro mid 2012 to a 3d projector

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, macbook, macbook-pro, thunderbolt

I have a question regarding connecting my Macbook Pro mid 2012 to a 3d projector.

So I understood my 3d projector has HDMI input and I need to connect it with my Macbook Pro.

I was a bit confused with mini display port and thunderbolt. As I understood my Macbook Pro Mid 2012 has thunderbolt 1, am I right.

So then I need to buy, Thunderbolt 1 to HDMI adapter. Mini Display port to HDMI will not work as I understood.

But then I searched through internet and found this [adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NH13K8S) which description says that it's Mini Display port (thunderbolt) - HDMI adapter.

Currently I can't understand what should buy... There are only two points that I want to connect my Macbook Thunderbolt 1 port and HDMI port on my projector, which cable you can advice.

To summarize here are few important question to understood:

1. Macbook Pro mid 2012 contains Thunderbolt 1 port (up to 10GB) YES/NO
2. Is there any difference between Mini Display Port and Thunderbolt 1. Can I buy Mini Display Port to HDMI to output 3d HD video to my projector via Macbook Pro mid 2012.

Comment: I've not enough detail to provide an answer, but essentially Thunderbolt is an active technology, smart, 2-way. It uses the same plug/sockets as miniDP & is backwardly-compatible. So, unless you also *need* thunderbolt at the 'far end' [in your case not, as you're only carrying video, one way] then you can always use a miniDP cable in a Thunderbolt socket.

Comment: @Tetsujin, ok great, thank you, I bought one yesterday. I will answer if it works)